# Calling functions through Iterator?

Tags: c++, function, iterator

In class Faculty, I have a set of Subjects. I want to go through this set and on each subject call a function that adds a student to this subject.
Here is how my function looks.

```
void Faculty::addStudent(Student* n) {
    this->Students.insert(n);
    set<Subject*>::iterator it;

    for(it = this->Subjects.begin(); it != this->Subjects.end(); it++) {
        (*it)->addStudent(n);
    }
}
```

The problem is that I get an error:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x01341c6d in University.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x1000694d.
```

I am using Micorosft Visual 2010.

I am new to C++.

I can provide any other necessary information, just don't know which. Please tell me if something is needed.

```
class Student: public Human {
    friend class University;
    friend class Faculty;
    friend class Subject;
public:
    Student(string name, string surname);
    ~Student();
    void Index(int n);
private:
    int index;
};
```

Comment: How you are populating the set? looks like a classic case of using objects which are already destroyed.

Comment: Add the definition of `addStudent` at the very least.

Comment: `set<Subject*>` means that the subjects aren't owned by this set object. You do have them stored safely at some other place?

Comment: The set isn't yet populated.

I dont know TT. I think they are not owned by this set. I create them, then I assign pointers to this set (I think so).

Comment: I have the impression that the Subjects are deleted somewhere before this method has been called

Comment: If you step through it in debug mode or whatever, you can find out exactly what the problem is, and where it occurs. "Access Violation" is a bit too vague here. Also, consider using `std::shared_ptr<Student>` instead of `Student*`

Answer (score 10):

In most cases, such this, better practice is using [smart pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer) instead of raw data pointers when data shared between two or more classes.

Example. At first, we wrap pointers like this:

```
typedef shared_ptr<Student> StudentSPtr;
typedef shared_ptr<Subject> SubjectSPtr;
```

After this, we replace raw pointers by these pointers (`StudentSptr n` instead of `Student* n`) in the entire code. So, your function may look like this:

```
void Faculty::addStudent(StudentSptr n){
  this->Students.insert(n);
  vector<SubjectSPtr>::iterator it;  //in your case vector is more proper, I think

  for(it = this->Subjects.begin(); it != this->Subjects.end(); it++){
    (*it)->addStudent(n);
    }
}
```

Comment: You were extermly helpful :). Yes, I had to use smart pointers. I found that out myself (with the help of my gf). It was that the objects were being destroyed and pointers were pointing to nothing.

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @user1455380 The best way to thank is to upvote and accept helpful answer.